# How to import site into Local by flywheel using existing file directory only, and no sql file

Tags: import

This guide indicates that you need both a file directory and sql file to accomplish this, does anyone know a workaround?

https://localwp.com/help-docs/how-to-import-a-wordpress-site-into-local/

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the backup archives from the starting-site folder. Within your WordPress folder, navigate to wp-content -> uploads -> backwpup-xxxxxx-backups. Open the archive. Inside you’ll find a .SQL file (local.sql).